# Wordpress Cookies - wp_set_auth_cookie

Tags: login, cookies

I would like to make the login working to all of my wordpress sites. They are single installs, so no multisite plugins can help. I decided to go with the cookies.
I store the users in the same usertable and metatable.

Please check out my code.
The auth, the salt and the other security encription keys are the same, I have defined the directory of the loginsessions. I have also defined cookiehash and it's buddies, because the are going to be the names of the cookies.

```
define('AUTH_KEY', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
define('NONCE_KEY', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
define('AUTH_SALT',        'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
define('NONCE_SALT',       'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
define('COOKIEHASH', md5('linkyou'));
define('USER_COOKIE', 'linkyouuser_' . COOKIEHASH);
define('PASS_COOKIE', 'linkyoupass_' . COOKIEHASH);
define('AUTH_COOKIE', 'linkyou_' . COOKIEHASH);
define('SECURE_AUTH_COOKIE', 'linkyou_sec_' . COOKIEHASH);
define('LOGGED_IN_COOKIE', 'linkyou_logged_in_' . COOKIEHASH);
define('TEST_COOKIE', 'linkyou_test_cookie');
session_save_path('/home/content/86/9513386/html/loginsessions');
```

The thing is I have edited `wp_set_auth_cookie()` and `wp_clear_auth_cookie()`,
Reference from codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_auth_cookie
The function is located in a core file: wp-includes/pluggable.php

I think wp_set_auth_cookie() must be the mayor problem, please check out the code:
Original

```
function wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id, $remember = false, $secure = '') {
    if ( $remember ) {
        $expiration = time() + apply_filters('auth_cookie_expiration', 14 * DAY_IN_SECONDS, $user_id, $remember);
        // Ensure the browser will continue to send the cookie after the expiration time is reached.
        // Needed for the login grace period in wp_validate_auth_cookie().
        $expire = $expiration + ( 12 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
    } else {
        $expiration = time() + apply_filters('auth_cookie_expiration', 2 * DAY_IN_SECONDS, $user_id, $remember);
        $expire = 0;
    }

    if ( '' === $secure )
        $secure = is_ssl();

    $secure = apply_filters('secure_auth_cookie', $secure, $user_id);
    $secure_logged_in_cookie = apply_filters('secure_logged_in_cookie', false, $user_id, $secure);

    if ( $secure ) {
        $auth_cookie_name = SECURE_AUTH_COOKIE;
        $scheme = 'secure_auth';
    } else {
        $auth_cookie_name = AUTH_COOKIE;
        $scheme = 'auth';
    }

    $auth_cookie = wp_generate_auth_cookie($user_id, $expiration, $scheme);
    $logged_in_cookie = wp_generate_auth_cookie($user_id, $expiration, 'logged_in');

    do_action('set_auth_cookie', $auth_cookie, $expire, $expiration, $user_id, $scheme);
    do_action('set_logged_in_cookie', $logged_in_cookie, $expire, $expiration, $user_id, 'logged_in');

    setcookie($auth_cookie_name, $auth_cookie, $expire, PLUGINS_COOKIE_PATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, $secure, true);
    setcookie($auth_cookie_name, $auth_cookie, $expire, ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, $secure, true);
    setcookie(LOGGED_IN_COOKIE, $logged_in_cookie, $expire, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, $secure_logged_in_cookie, true);
    if ( COOKIEPATH != SITECOOKIEPATH )
        setcookie(LOGGED_IN_COOKIE, $logged_in_cookie, $expire, SITECOOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, $secure_logged_in_cookie, true);
}
```

Edited version

```
function wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id, $remember = false, $secure = '') {
    if ( $remember ) {
        $expiration = time() + apply_filters('auth_cookie_expiration', 14 * DAY_IN_SECONDS, $user_id, $remember);
        // Ensure the browser will continue to send the cookie after the expiration time is reached.
        // Needed for the login grace period in wp_validate_auth_cookie().
        $expire = $expiration + ( 12 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
    } else {
        $expiration = time() + apply_filters('auth_cookie_expiration', 2 * DAY_IN_SECONDS, $user_id, $remember);
        $expire = 0;
    }

    if ( '' === $secure )
        $secure = is_ssl();

    $secure = apply_filters('secure_auth_cookie', $secure, $user_id);
    $secure_logged_in_cookie = apply_filters('secure_logged_in_cookie', false, $user_id, $secure);

    if ( $secure ) {
        $auth_cookie_name = SECURE_AUTH_COOKIE;
        $scheme = 'secure_auth';
    } else {
        $auth_cookie_name = AUTH_COOKIE;
        $scheme = 'auth';
    }

    $auth_cookie = wp_generate_auth_cookie($user_id, $expiration, $scheme);
    $logged_in_cookie = wp_generate_auth_cookie($user_id, $expiration, 'logged_in');

    do_action('set_auth_cookie', $auth_cookie, $expire, $expiration, $user_id, $scheme);
    do_action('set_logged_in_cookie', $logged_in_cookie, $expire, $expiration, $user_id, 'logged_in');

    setcookie($auth_cookie_name, $auth_cookie, $expire, 'gamerspost.us/wp-content/plugins', 'gamerspost.us', $secure, true);
    setcookie($auth_cookie_name, $auth_cookie, $expire, 'gamerspost.us/wp-admin', 'gamerspost.us', $secure, true);
    setcookie(LOGGED_IN_COOKIE, $logged_in_cookie, $expire, 'gamerspost.us/', 'gamerspost.us', $secure_logged_in_cookie, true);

    setcookie($auth_cookie_name, $auth_cookie, $expire, 'linkwave.us/wp-content/plugins', 'linkwave.us', $secure, true);
    setcookie($auth_cookie_name, $auth_cookie, $expire, 'linkwave.us/wp-admin', 'linkwave.us', $secure, true);
    setcookie(LOGGED_IN_COOKIE, $logged_in_cookie, $expire, 'linkwave.us/', 'linkwave.us', $secure_logged_in_cookie, true);

    setcookie($auth_cookie_name, $auth_cookie, $expire, 'linkyou.us/wp-content/plugins', 'linkyou.us', $secure, true);
    setcookie($auth_cookie_name, $auth_cookie, $expire, 'linkyou.us/wp-admin', 'linkyou.us', $secure, true);
    setcookie(LOGGED_IN_COOKIE, $logged_in_cookie, $expire, 'linkyou.us/', 'linkyou.us', $secure_logged_in_cookie, true);

    setcookie($auth_cookie_name, $auth_cookie, $expire, 'linkmusic.us/wp-content/plugins', 'linkmusic.us', $secure, true);
    setcookie($auth_cookie_name, $auth_cookie, $expire, 'linkmusic.us/wp-admin', 'linkmusic.us', $secure, true);
    setcookie(LOGGED_IN_COOKIE, $logged_in_cookie, $expire, 'linkmusic.us/', 'linkmusic.us', $secure_logged_in_cookie, true);

    setcookie($auth_cookie_name, $auth_cookie, $expire, 'linkask.us/wp-content/plugins', 'linkask.us', $secure, true);
    setcookie($auth_cookie_name, $auth_cookie, $expire, 'linkask.us/wp-admin', 'linkask.us', $secure, true);
    setcookie(LOGGED_IN_COOKIE, $logged_in_cookie, $expire, 'linkask.us/', 'linkask.us', $secure_logged_in_cookie, true);
    /*if ( COOKIEPATH != SITECOOKIEPATH )
        setcookie(LOGGED_IN_COOKIE, $logged_in_cookie, $expire, 'gamerspost.us/', 'gamerspost.us', $secure_logged_in_cookie, true);
        setcookie(LOGGED_IN_COOKIE, $logged_in_cookie, $expire, 'linkwave.us/', 'linkwave.us', $secure_logged_in_cookie, true);
        setcookie(LOGGED_IN_COOKIE, $logged_in_cookie, $expire, 'linkyou.us/', 'linkyou.us', $secure_logged_in_cookie, true);
        setcookie(LOGGED_IN_COOKIE, $logged_in_cookie, $expire, 'linkmusic.us/', 'linkmusic.us', $secure_logged_in_cookie, true);
        setcookie(LOGGED_IN_COOKIE, $logged_in_cookie, $expire, 'linkask.us/', 'linkask.us', $secure_logged_in_cookie, true);*/
}
```

`wp_clear_auth_cookie()` is created by mostly the same method, but it comes up when you are logging out, if you want I can post that here.

Any thoughs?
Thank you in advance! :D

Comment: What is your question?  FYI, you cannot set cookies on another domain.  If the user is logging into domain1.com, you cannot set cookies for: domain2.com, domain3.com, etc.

Comment: Yeh, you must be right, Thank you for your answer!